# "Can't write to sqlite.dll" error in RoR on Windows

Tags: windows, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

I have installed RoR in normal way as told on the RoR Guides website. It is installed, then few months ago I used it and it worked fine, now after some months when I create a new app and give this command

```
rake db:create
```

It gives the error that it can't write to sqlite.dll file, it gives the path of Ruby installation folder and its bin folder. I have downloaded and copy sqlite.exe and sql.dll in that folder also but same problem.

I thought that may be some thing is corrupted so I have reinstalled ruby and RoR. But nothing happen, same error continues. Please tell me also if it don't simply work on Windows. I am using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2.